# How Can I Set Up Multiple Copy Link Buttons on the Same Page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, copy

I have been dealing with this for about 2 weeks now.

Summary:
This is related to copying a link within a page.  I know how to do it using CTRL-C to copy, but I want to offer a button that users can click on to copy the link from within the page.

Overview
I have about 100 PDFs that are links appear on the same page.  I want to add a Copy Link button for each one. Each Copy Link button will be independent to grab the respective PDF URL.

Sample:

```
'PDF One'  -  Copy Link Button  (this will copy the 'PDF One' URL)
'PDF Two'  -  Copy Link Button  (this will copy the 'PDF Two' URL)
'PDF Three'  -  Copy Link Button  (this will copy the 'PDF Three' URL)
```

...etc, etc, etc.

I have tried about 6 different scripts so far and all basically focuses either the URL of the address bar or it functions just for only one thus it will not do more than two.

Any suggestions or code snippet that will get me in the right direction?

Note: This is for a Wordpress site.

Thank you.

Comment: You just want to copy the link to the clipboard?

Comment: Maybe you show us the code you used that worked for one link, and it could probably be adapted. Also please provide some sample HTML of the links you're targeting

Comment: _Each Copy Link button will be independent to grab the respective PDF URL._ So where are you going to store these potentially multple copies? If you use the clipboard, the second copy will overwrite the first unless you capture the existing clipboard and merge the new copy. Then the issue would be "how do you plan to  process this odd clipboard content"

Comment: Basically without more detail of what you think you want to do with all these copies the question is firmly in the **Mystery Novel** catagory

Comment: I only need it to copy just one at a time.  This page will be for Reps only and so they will basically click on Copy Link and then paste it in their email and then go find another PDF and copy that link, etc. etc. etc.

I hope this make sense.  Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE:  I found what I was looking for that works.  I just was not googling it correctly.  I was trying to share the code but unfortunately, it was over the character  limit by 500+.  You can message me if you like and I will share the code. 

Thank you.

Comment: You can write your own answer

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using this code. Works flawlessly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // When a copy button is clicked
        $(".copy-button").on("click", function() {
            var urlToCopy = $(this).data("url");

            // Create a hidden input field to copy the URL text
            var $temp = $("<input>");
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val(urlToCopy).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();

            alert("Copied: " + urlToCopy);
        });
    });
</script>

<button class="copy-button" data-url="https://example.com/link1">Copy Link 1</button>
<button class="copy-button" data-url="https://example.com/link2">Copy Link 2</button>
<button class="copy-button" data-url="https://example.com/link3">Copy Link 3</button>
```

Comment: Yep that makes perfect sense. Using a class selector means it can apply to as many buttons as there are on the page with the same class.